# WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records

Tags: nameserver

New to this website hosting and NS records so kindly be easy on me.
Kindly help me to resolve [this](http://www.intodns.com/jtrading.biz) this error.

spoke to my Hosting provider as well and they keep saying that I need to change the NS records or DNS records on my domain registrar website as I am still having old Nameserver. I did that but still I do not know what is the problem, I am keep receiving bounce back messages on email that I have created on my new domain and the website is also showing some Sorry Message.

Kindly let me know where do I need to go and what I need to change in order to make my site and emails live.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the delegatory `NS` records in the parent zone:

```
jtrading.biz.           7200    IN      NS      NS305.FASTWEBHOST.COM.
jtrading.biz.           7200    IN      NS      NS306.FASTWEBHOST.COM.
;; Received 291 bytes from 2001:503:7bbb:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff7e#53(a.gtld.biz) in 15 ms
```

with the `NS` records returned by the servers indicated in the delegation:

```
jtrading.biz.           86400   IN      NS      ns303.fastwebhost.com.
jtrading.biz.           86400   IN      NS      ns304.fastwebhost.com.
;; Received 96 bytes from 72.52.226.109#53(NS306.FASTWEBHOST.COM) in 103 ms
```

you will notice that there is a mismatch.

Using the command `dig +trace +add example.com NS` it's easy to get an overview of the chain of delegations for a domain, allowing you to check this kind of thing for yourself.

To fix the current problem, first of all you will need to figure out which nameservers you are actually supposed to be using for this domain. Once you know that, you will want to either change the delegation (through your registrar), your own zone (at the nameservers that you use to host this zone) or possibly both depending on where there are currently incorrect `NS` records.

The `NS` records in the delegation and the `NS` record at the authoritative nameservers are supposed to agree.